# Dividing data sets into testing and training data

Tags: machine-learning, partition, training-data

I have a dataset with k examples and I want to partition into m sets.
How can I do it programmatically.
For example, if k = 5 and m = 2, therefore, 5 / 2 = 2.5
How do I partition it into the 2 and 3, and not 2, 2 and 1?
Similarly, if k = 10 and m = 3, I want it to be partitioned into 3, 3 and 4, but not 3, 3, 3 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this sort of functionality is built into tools.  But, assuming that your observations are independent, just set up a random number generator and do something like:

```
for i = 1 to k do;
    set r = rand();
    if r < 0.5 then data[i].which = 'set1'
    else data[i].which = 'set2'
```

You can extend this for any number of sets and probabilities.

For an example where k = 5, then you could actually get all the rows in a single set (I'm thinking about 3% of the time).  However, the point of splitting data is for dealing with larger amounts of data.  If you only have 5 or 10 rows, then splitting your observations into different partitions is probably not the way to go.